# Blockchain/decentralized apps development intro

Tags: blockchain

I would like to get my hands dirty and start playing with a pet project to get into blockchain technologies.

Some time ago I read Mastering Bitcoin and now am looking for a concise intro into using blockchains. Perhaps something like the Decentralized Applications book (not published yet) book could be.

Any tips for books, articles, etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for books, try this [link](https://cointelegraph.com/news/five-books-on-blockchain-and-bitcoin-you-may-need-right-now). If you are looking to do more of a hands on approach for learning how blockchain works. Try a sample application like this one [here](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/cp-web)

Answer (score 1):

try Microsoft Blockchain as a service, they have strato which has REST based APIs for easier development, it actually uses Ethereum framework

Answer (score -1):

This is the best one I have come across in regards to building DApps with Ethereum. It is concise and straight to the point.

Book: Introducing Ethereum and Solidity: Foundations of Cryptocurrency and Blockchain Programming for Beginners

Author: Chris Dannen

[Book Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484225341)

[Github of the Author](https://github.com/chrisdannen)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16488624)

Comment: right. just edited!

This is one of the most useful books out there for Blockchain dev. I have struggled a lot to find the right material. I believe this will be helpful to a lot of people. 

The process maybe incorrect to post but the information is still very useful.